# MOUSE-EXTEND-CLICK EVENT in Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge 11.6

Tags: .net, datagridview, openedge

I'm currently working on DataGridView Events and converting Progress 4GL code into .NET classes. How do I write 'ON MOUSE-EXTEND-CLICK OF b1(browse)' in Progress Developer Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests I found the answer

```
METHOD PRIVATE VOID dgvB1_CellClick( INPUT sender AS System.Object, INPUT e 
    AS System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs ):

    IF AVAILABLE tt AND e:RowIndex GT -1 THEN
    DO:
        IF System.Windows.Forms.Control:ModifierKeys = System.Windows.Forms.Keys:CONTROL THEN
        DO:
            MESSAGE tt.field VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
        END.
        RETURN.
    END.
END METHOD.
```